# Чтение фреймов с вебкамеры

Tags: c++, opencv, web-camera

Появилась необходимость обрабатывать фреймы с вебкамеры, выбрал *OpenCV*. Так вот, эта програмулька для чтения выдает ошибку:

> Unhandled exception at 0x00007FF959C7E5BC (ntdll.dll) in CaptureVideo.exe: 0xC000000D : Службе или функции передан неверный параметр.

В окне видно вместо изображения полоски.

Код:

```
#include <opencv\cv.h>
#include <opencv\highgui.h>
int main() {
    cvNamedWindow("Output", 0);
    CvCapture* capture = cvCreateCameraCapture(0);
    //assert(capture != NULL);
    IplImage* frame = cvQueryFrame(capture);
    cvShowImage("Output", frame);
    //cvSaveImage("filename.png", frame);
    cvWaitKey (2000);

    cvDestroyWindow("Output");
    return 0;
}
```

Проблема в строчке:

```
CvCapture* capture = cvCreateCameraCapture(0);
```

При нулевом значении выходит ошибка, а при других константах (`СV_CAP_*`) нету ни изображения, ни ошибки. 
На всякий: камера ноутбука. В скайпе как и на сайтах камера работает.

Comment: а версия openCV какая???

Comment: Версия 3.1.0(последняя)

Comment: у меня возникло пра вопросов к вам, свяжитесь со мной

Comment: Да, слушаю вас.

Comment: у меня в проделе адрес пометы напишите туда.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

using namespace cv;

int main(int, char**)
{
    VideoCapture cap(0); // открываем камеру
    if(!cap.isOpened())  // 

    Mat edges;
    namedWindow("edges",1);
    for(;;)
    {
        Mat frame;
        cap >> frame; // получаем кадры от камеры
        cvtColor(frame, edges, COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
        GaussianBlur(edges, edges, Size(7,7), 1.5, 1.5);
        Canny(edges, edges, 0, 30, 3);
        imshow("edges", edges);
        if(waitKey(30) >= 0) break;
    }
    // деструктор
    return 0;
}
```